# Cómo obtener los datos del usuario logueado con Laravel Auth

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación con Laravel y he utilizado el `auth` de Laravel para todo el tema de autenticación, como sabrán cuando utilizas el `auth` de Laravel se crean la vista de login, registro y home.

Lo que yo quiero saber es como ver la información del usuario que acaba de loguearse, es decir que cuando la persona ingrese, en la vista de home se muestre por ejemplo, su nombre, correo.

Esta es la vista home cuando el usuario ingresa:

```
    @section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Inicio</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    Usted ha iniciado Sesion
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si está utilizando el modelo `User` por defecto. Simplemente tiene la opción de usar

```
auth()->user() // Obtenemos la instancia del usuario logueado
```

Que retornará una instancia del modelo `User` logueado , a partir de este, puede acceder a los atributos como `email` , `name` u otros que tenga en su tabla, además relaciones establecidas con  `Eloquent`

```
auth()->user()->name
auth()->user()->email
```

Para obtener el Id puede hacerse de la forma anterior accediendo a `auth()->user()->id` pero hay una forma más corta

```
auth()->id();
```

Para mostrar los datos en la vista deberá hacerse con la sintaxis de blade tradicional

```
  <div class="card-body">

     <h4>Bienvenido . {{ auth()->user()->name }} </h4>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder... ese código lo colocaría en la vista o en el modelo?

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: Gracias por la información.

Comment: Se que escribiste esto hace años pero me ayudaste y te queria agradecer... a ti y a San Google xDD

Comment: Excelente me funcionó gracias, ahora ya puedo mostrar el name que viene desde la base de datos...