# ¿Como obtengo datos del Auth por medio del API en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Estoy haciendo mi Auth con Ajax, y después de tantos intentos lo logré, pero ahora quiero obtener los datos desde la API de mis rutas para mostrarlos, ya que trabajo con los componentes de Vue y no con Blade.

Intenté [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/160151/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-los-datos-del-usuario-logueado-con-laravel-auth) pero no me funciona, este es mi código con el que intenté:

```
Route::get('userdata', function(Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
    return response()->json([
        'auth' => auth()->user(),
        'user' => $request->user()
    ]);
});
```

Pero los dos me lanza null. Eso es mi `api.php`. Cabe aclarar que con `web.php` si me da correctamente los datos, pero quiero obtenerlo desde API pues todo mi sistema estoy trabajando con API

Paso el código del Login por si es necesario:

```
public function login( Request $request ){
        $crendential = $request->only('email', 'password');
        $authSuccess = Auth::attempt($crendential, $request->has('remember'));

        if($authSuccess) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return response(['success' => true], 200);
        }
        return
            response([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Auth failded (or some other message)'
            ], 403);        
    }
```

Mi idea, es que cuando el usuario inicie sesión, este sea redireccionado a `/home` y con Vue consultar a `/api/userdata` y poder obtener los datos para mostrar en los componentes cargados en `/home`.

Comment: Estas usando api_tokens? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication

Comment: No, realmente no. Ni sabia de eso, es necesario?

Comment: Si luis, mírate un poco esa información e inténtalo.

Comment: Como te dice pwron, si usas las rutas de `routes/api.php`, debes configurar una autenticación, la default de Laravel o con passport. Luego puedes poner la ruta dentro del middleware  'auth:api', que tendrá la información para devolver del usuario logueado `Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function(Request $request) { return auth()->user(); });`.